# URL Rewrite Filemap Provider equivalent in Azure App Services?

Tags: iis, azure, rewrite, azure-app-services

I have an application that I am migrating from IaaS to Azure PaaS.

This application has a significant dependency on IIS Rewrite rules using the External Rewrite Map provider (specifically, we're using [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43353)). We have a few basic rewrite rules in our web.config, an external redirects.config, and thousands of dynamic redirects stemming from a CMS driven database.

Is there an equivalent redirect management functionality in Azure that I can leverage to still enable redirect rules to come from either SQL or a flat file that the application updates periodically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there isn't one.

I ended up having to implement functionality from scratch to achieve similar behavior.